# RegEx that gives letters not enclosed by parentheses

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to write a regular expression that gives me letters that are not enclosed by parentheses. It should not give me any letters in any parentheses.

### **For example:**

If the input is **x+y^(a+b*c)+z** 
it should give me **x**, **y**, and **z**, but not **a**, **b**, and **c**

I've tried this but it didn't work:

```js
/[^\(][a-z][^\)]/g
```

Test strings:

```js
"x+y^(a+b)+z"         // should return ["x", "y", "z"]
"x+y^(a+b)+z*(c-d)/w" // should return ["x", "y", "z", "w"]
"x+y^(a+b*(c))+z"     // should return ["x", "y", "z"]
```

Also, the indexes of all the letters in the original string are needed.

Please answer with an explanation

Comment: You mean, also without the string symbols? (`+`. `^`)

Comment: do you need to handle nested parenthesis?

Comment: Yes, as you can see this is a mathematical expression and I want to get variables that are not enclosed in parentheses. @luiscla27

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two solutions:

```js
strings = [
  'x+y^(a+b)+z',
  'x+y^(a+b+c)+q+z',
  'x+y^(a+b)+p+q^(c+d)+z'
].forEach(str => {
  let match1 = str.match(/(?<!\([^\)]*)[a-z]+/g);
  let match2 = str.replace(/\^\([^\)]*/g, '').match(/[a-z]+/g);
  console.log(str + ' =>'
    + '\n  match1: ' + match1
    + '\n  match2: ' + match2);
});
```

Output:

```
x+y^(a+b)+z =>
  match1: x,y,z
  match2: x,y,z
x+y^(a+b+c)+q+z =>
  match1: x,y,q,z
  match2: x,y,q,z
x+y^(a+b)+p+q^(c+d)+z =>
  match1: x,y,p,q,z
  match2: x,y,p,q,z
```

Explanation for match1:

- `.match(/(?<!\([^\)]*)[a-z]+/g)` -- negative lookbehind for `^(...` pattern
- note that negative lookbehind does not work in all browsers, notably Safari

Explanation for match2:

- `.replace(/\^\([^\)]*/g, '')` -- remove all `^(...)` patterns
- `.match(/[a-z]+/g)` -- simple match for letters

Do you have nested parenthesis? This is possible too with pre-tagging parenthesis with nesting level. Let me know.

Comment: Your answer looks the same as Roko's, I deleted mine because it was the same thing as yours.

Comment: It looks like we were editing the answer at the same time

Comment: Thank you, the regex in the match1 is exactly what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

For your specific case you could use negative lookbehind / lookahead:

```bash
(?<!\()[a-z](?!\))
```

https://regex101.com/r/C0L228/1

Example:

```js
const rootSymbols = /(?<!\()[a-z](?!\))/g;
console.log("x+y^(a+b)+z".match(rootSymbols)); // ["x", "y", "z"]
```

If you have **nested brackets**, I think the simplest is to get first rid of them:

```js
const rootSymbols = (str) => str.replace(/\(.*\)/g, "").match(/[a-z]/g);
console.log(rootSymbols("x+y^(a+b-(c))+z")); // ["x", "y", "z"]
```

Comment: But when the input is " x+y^(a+b*(c))+z", it gives me b too.

Comment: @EnesGiray that's why I said: for your specific case. You did not disclosed all the possible rules in your question ;)

Comment: Sorry for that :( I will edit it.

Comment: @EnesGiray added another example for **nested brackets**.

Comment: And another point I forgot to mention in the question. so sorry. The main string should not change because I need the index info of the variables, and a variable may be used more than one time in the input. Yes, I can use your code, search in input again, and find the indices but I'm looking for a shorter solution. If I can't find it, I will choose your answer as correct. Thank you.

Comment: The nested cleanup won't work with multiple parenthesis at the same level `"x+y^(a+b-(c-d)))+p+^(e+f+(g-h))+z"` (not sure if this is a requirement though)

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan: The first regex does not work with 3+ letters in the parentesis: `"x+y^(a+b+c)+z".match(/(?<!\()[a-z](?!\))/g)` returns `['x', 'y', 'b', 'z']`

Answer (score 0):

Ugly JavaScript solution:

```js
const symbols = (str) => str.replace(/\(([^\)]+)/g, '').match(/[a-z]+/g)?.map(a => ({letter: a, index: str.indexOf(a)}));

console.log(symbols("x+y^(a+b)+z")); // ["x", "y", "z"] with indexes [0, 2, 10]
console.log(symbols("x+y^(a+b)+z*(c-d)/w")); // ["x", "y", "z", "w"] with indexes [0, 2, 10, 18]
console.log(symbols("x+y^(a+b*(c))+z")); // ["x", "y", "z"] with indexes [0, 2, 14]
```

Inner parentheses symbols are removed first and then the remaining is matched, after that indexes are added, final objects looks like this:

```js
// "x+y^(a+b)+z*(c-d)/w"
[
    {
        "letter": "x",
        "index": 0
    },
    {
        "letter": "y",
        "index": 2
    },
    {
        "letter": "z",
        "index": 10
    },
    {
        "letter": "w",
        "index": 18
    }
]
```

Comment: Already posted a similar solution ;)

Comment: Similar indeed, just edited it to include a difference :)